# What's the easiest way to search a MS ACCESS Table of Replacement for all numbers that are related? Better explanation in description

Tags: sql, ms-access

Sample table:

Ba  Re
10  40
20  60
30  70
 
40  30
50  90

The left column is the base column and the right is the replace column.

If I provide "10", I want a column with these values in it:

10
40
30
70

...since 10 is replaced by 40, 40 is replaced by 30 and 30 is replaced by 70.
I also want the exact same result if I provide 30,40 or 70.

I have managed to do this with a combination of queries in series that take forever to execute, since the table is big and so are the real life numbers.

Is there a quicker and better way to achieve this?

In short, this is what I've done:
I've created a query that first checks for replacements for the basenumber.
I combine the results into a column through UNION SELECT.
I've then created a query that checks for basenumbers for the results from the first pass.
I then combine the final result again though UNION SELECT.
There are two major flaws in my solution.
1. It takes forever!
2. If the number I'm looking for has no replacement, my result is empty. Even if the table doesn't have a replacement, I want the final column to pass on the input number anyway.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]! Seems like you want to do a recursion, but ms access is not capable of this in queries. You have to create that in VBA (slow) or switch to anRDBMS like SQL-Server, MySQL, Postgre, etc as Backend.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the warm welcome! Well, I did solve it with queries but it's not a clean execution. :) Looking into Gustav's solution right now but didn't quite get it to work. Yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple loop to walk the values in a snap.

Here, they will just print, but you could add them to a table or listbox:

```vb
Public Function RecursiveList( _
    ByVal Ba As Long) _
    As Long

    Dim dbs      As Database
    Dim rst      As Recordset

    Set dbs = CurrentDb()
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("Select * From Sample")

    With rst
        .MoveFirst
        Do
            Debug.Print , Ba
            .FindFirst "Ba = " & Ba
            If Not .NoMatch Then
                Ba = !Re.Value
            End If
        Loop Until .NoMatch
    End With

    RecursiveList = Ba

End Function
```

Output:

```vb
               10 
               40 
               30 
               70 
 70
```

Comment: Hey Gustav. So I'm trying this approach to the problem right now but I'm not getting the expected output so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong. I'll poke around a bit more before I give up and come running back for more help. :)

Comment: Can't tell. I just created a table with your sample data, and it worked right away.